# WPF OnKeyUp in UserControl not firing

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, onkeyup, onkeydown

I have Window with UserControl. I subscribed for OnKeyUp event but it does not firing.
Inside UserControl constructor i use method this.Focus();
But still onkeyup does not firing.
What is wrong and what i can to do to catch this event?

Comment: as in some controls the keyup events don't work , keydown event works and in some controls vice-versa, this i am talking about silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the silverlight scenario , I cannot say it will work in wpf!

keyUp event gets fired of the usercontrol and it works great , here is the code snippet how to register the event handler for KeyUp of usercontrol :

```
 this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(MainPage_KeyUp);


        void MainPage_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Strange but Window or MainPage KeyUp is firing but in usercontrol it is always not active. I will create method in child controls and will pass clicked key to them. Hope this will help. Thanks for reply.